# d3 lines between dots not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, lines, scatter

I have made a scatter plot using d3 and want to connect the dots with lines, I have tried using what people have written online to connect the lines but it does not seem to be working.

```
function makeGraph(sampleData){
    console.log(sampleData);
    var vis = d3.select("#svgVisualize");

    yMax = d3.max(sampleData, function (point) {return point.y;});

    //step 1 : scale the data

    xRange = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(sampleData.map(function (d) { return d.x; })).rangePoints([0, 700]);
    yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([400, 40]).domain([0, yMax]);


    //step 2: scale the axis
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xRange);
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yRange).orient("left");

    //Step3: append the x and y axis
    vis.append('svg:g')
            .call(xAxis)
            .attr("transform", "translate(90,400)")
            .append("text")
            .text("Build Model")
            .attr("y", 70)
            .attr("x", 150);
    vis.append('svg:g')
            .call(yAxis)
            .attr("transform", "translate(90,0)")
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", -80)
            .attr("x", -130)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Number of Users");

    var circles = vis.selectAll("circle").data(sampleData);

    circles
            .enter()
            .insert("circle")
            .attr("cx", function (d) {return xRange(d.x);})
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return yRange(d.y); })
            .attr("r", 4)
            .attr("transform", "translate(90,0)")
            .style("fill", "blue");
    var lineFunction = vis.line()
            .x(function (d) {
              return d.x;
            })
            .y(function (d) {
              return d.y;
            })
            .interpolate("linear");

    vis.append("path")
            .attr("d", lineFunction(sampleData))
            .style("stroke-width", 0.5)
            .style("stroke", "rgb(6,120,155)")
            .style("fill", "none")
            .on("mouseover", function () {
              d3.select(this)
                      .style("stroke", "orange");
            })
            .on("mouseout", function () {
              d3.select(this)
                      .style("stroke", "rgb(6,120,155)");
            });
}
```

If anyone could help that would be great, I'm still new to d3

Answer (score 1):

Your example is working fine, I had to do the following

- Change the line that creates a path generator to `d3.svg.line` (just like Gerardo's answer)
- Create a group for your circles and the path so that you don't have to add `.attr("transform", "translate(90,0)")` to both of them
- Use a [data join](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) for the path (although it's not required)

```js
function makeGraph(sampleData) {
  var svg = d3.select('#svgVisualize')

  yMax = d3.max(sampleData, function(point) {
    return point.y;
  });

  xRange = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(sampleData.map(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })).rangePoints([0, 700]);
  yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([400, 40]).domain([0, yMax]);


  //step 2: scale the axis
  xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xRange);
  yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yRange).orient("left");

  //Step3: append the x and y axis
  svg.append('svg:g')
    .call(xAxis)
    .attr("transform", "translate(90,400)")
    .append("text")
    .text("Build Model")
    .attr("y", 70)
    .attr("x", 150);
  svg.append('svg:g')
    .call(yAxis)
    .attr("transform", "translate(90,0)")
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", -80)
    .attr("x", -130)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Number of Users");
  
  // data
  var g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'data')
    .attr("transform", "translate(90,0)")


  var circles = g.selectAll("circle").data(sampleData);
  circles
    .enter()
    .insert("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return xRange(d.x);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return yRange(d.y);
    })
    .attr("r", 4)
    .style("fill", "blue");
  
  var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xRange(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return yRange(d.y); })
    .interpolate("linear");
  var path = g.selectAll('path').data([sampleData])
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr("d", lineFunction)
    .style("stroke-width", 0.5)
    .style("stroke", "rgb(6,120,155)")
    .style("fill", "none")
    .on("mouseover", function() {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("stroke", "orange");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("stroke", "rgb(6,120,155)");
    });
}

makeGraph([
  {x: 0, y: 100},
  {x: 100, y: 100},
  {x: 200, y: 200},
  {x: 300, y: 100}
])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg id="svgVisualize" width="900" height="500" style="position: relative; left: 2%;"></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The line function has to be like this:

```
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xRange(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return yRange(d.y); })
    .interpolate("linear");
```

Comment: I made the changes, but I still get an error saying that this part is not a function:

Comment: vis.append("path")
                  .datum(sampleData)
                  .enter()
                  .attr("d", lineFunction)
                  .style("stroke-width", 0.5)
                  .style("stroke", "rgb(6,120,155)")
                  .style("fill", "none");
        }

Comment: Just changed the answer, try now.

Comment: Wait a minute, are you seeing the circles, or anything at all? I can't see you appending the SVG in your code.

Comment: Yes I appended the svg (my bad, I just didn't show that line in my code), and I added the changes but I still get that error, but when I change datum to data, the error goes away but the lines don't appear still

Comment: What's the variable to append the svg?

Comment: I am using jade, so I have this line:  svg(id="svgVisualize" width="900" height="500" style="position: relative; left: 2%;"), and then I do var vis = d3.select("#svgVisualize"); in my script and I append everything to vis

Comment: OK, I changed the answer back. That's my best shot, let's see if anyone else can help you. Cheers.